# Oracle sqlldr : remove delimiter

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have a NPWP column that contains the numbers shown below :

npwp

```
012345678-613.001
001234565-005.000
```

and npwp's table

```
create table npwp (
no_npwp varchar2(15)
)
```

how to tell loader.ctl in order to remove the mark `-` and `.` ?

like that ?

```
OPTIONS (SKIP=11, errors=12000) 
LOAD DATA  
APPEND INTO TABLE npwp (
npwp POSITION(1:9)||POSITION(11:3)||POSITION(15:3))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sql expressions. For instance:

```
APPEND INTO TABLE npwp (
  npwp "REPLACE(REPLACE(:npwp ,'-'),'.')"
)
```

or

```
APPEND INTO TABLE npwp (
  npwp "substr(:npwp, 1, 9) || substr(:npwp, 11, 3) || substr(:npwp, 15)"
)
```